# Question about switch-case statement

Tags: programming-languages, c

What happens, and does code work properly if we write switch-case structure like this, why its not good to write code like this? I'm porting some firmware and have switch-case statement interrupted like this one, and when I remove code between that switch-case statements, it begins to operate normally.

```
switch(state){
    case 0:
    break;
    case 1:
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
    case 3:
    break;
}

//here we interrupt switch-case and do a some other code


// after that code we continue with same switch

switch(state){
    case 4:
    break;
    case 5:
    break;
    case 6:
    break;
    case 7:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the missing opening curly brace in the second statement which I guess is a typo: Those are just two independent switch statements from a technical view. If this does not work as expected there may be some logical error in the code you removed (e.g. the state variable was changed?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the code in the middle is changing the value of the **state** variable, giving you different execution in the second switch statement.  Presumably, this matters; create a new variable, store the value of **state** into it and use this in the second switch statement:

```
int savedState = state ; 
switch( savedState ) { ... } // 0, 1, 2, 3 
// Other Code 
switch( savedState ) { ... } // Everything else
```